# Sorting mails into $3$ boxes and find one mail

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

> A mail can be sent with equal probability to three mailboxes. If you check mailbox $i$ you find the mail with probability $0<p_i<1$ if the mail was indeed sent to this mailbox. (Imagine you did not read all mails but only did a quick carelss scan ...)
>
> Let's assume you have checked mailbox $1$ and did not find the mail, what is the probability that the mail has been sent to mailbox $1$ although you have checked mailbox $1$?

---

Let be $M_i$ the event that the mail was sent to mailbox $i$,

$S_i$ the event that you have checked mailbox $i$ and found the mail and

$S_i^c$ is the event that you have checked mailbox $i$ and did not find the mail.

We are looking for the conditional probability $P(M_1\mid S_1^c)$. We know that $P(S_1\mid M_1)=p_1\iff P(S_1^c\mid M_1)=1-p_1$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
&P(M_1\mid S_1^c)=\frac{P(M_1\cap S_1^c)}{P(S_1^c)}\frac{P(M_1)}{P(M_1)}=(1-p_1)\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{P(S_1^c)},\\
&P(S_1^c)=1-P(S_1)=1-(P(S_1\mid M_1)P(M_1)+P(S_1\mid M_1^c)P(M_1^c))=1-\frac{p_1}{3}-0,\\
&\implies P(M_1\mid S_1^c)=\dots=\frac{(1-p_1)}{3-p_1}.
\end{align*}$$

I am not sure if I correctly translated the conditional probabilities. Is this correct?

Comment: There are two independent ways you can not find the mail: (1) the mail was sent to another another mailbox. Probability $\frac 23$. (2) The mail was sent to this mailbox, probability $\frac 13$, but you missed it, probability $1-p$, for an overall probability of $\frac{1-p}3$. So the total probability of not finding the mail in this mailbox is $$\frac23 +\frac {1-p}3 = 1 - \frac p3$$ as you calculated. However, for the rest of your calculation, how is it that $\frac{P(M)}{P(M)} = \dfrac{\frac 13}1$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair, I can't follow you. Why should $\frac{P(M)}{P(M)} = \dfrac{\frac 13}1$?

Comment: It shouldn't, which is why I am pointing out to you that you did exactly that in your calculation of $P(M_1\mid S_1^c)$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, No I didn't.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, It's simply the definition of the conditional probability: \begin{align*}
&P(M_1\mid S_1^c)=\frac{P(M_1\cap S_1^c)}{P(S_1^c)}\frac{P(M_1)}{P(M_1)}=P(S_1^c\mid M_1)\frac{P(M_1)}{P(S_1^c)}=(1-p_1)\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{P(S_1^c)}.
\end{align*} I did not use $\frac{P(M)}{P(M)} = \dfrac{\frac 13}1$

Comment: My apologies - I skimmed over that part and just took $P(M_1\cap S_1^c)$ to be $1-p_1$ instead of bothering to think it out myself. Your calculation is fully correct.